# tests pass when run individually but not when run together

Tags: jasmine, angular-test

I have a component for which I have written two test cases. Both test cases uses `setTimeout`. I notice that if I run the test cases together (in a single `describe`, the test cases fail but if I keep them in separate `describe`, the test cases pass. Why is it? The two test cases are

```
fit('should show dialog when message from DialogBoxService is received', () => {
      let dialogBoxService: MockDialogBoxService = TestBed.get(DialogBoxService);

      let dialogServiceContext = new DialogServiceContext(ComponentAndServiceID.QuestionDetailComponent, new QuestionDetailAdditionalInfo())
      /*
      At startup, there is a delay between creation of AppComponent and subscription to DialogService, I have added the test logic in setTimeout to give time for AppComponent to get created and also subscribe.
       */
      setTimeout(() => {
        spyOn(component, 'showDialog');
        dialogBoxService.emitDialogMessage(dialogServiceContext);
        expect(component.showDialog).toHaveBeenCalledWith(dialogServiceContext);
      }, 1000);
    });

    fit('should handle message from AuthGuard service', () => {
      let mockAuthGuard: MockAuthGuard = TestBed.get(AuthGuard);
      spyOn(component, 'handleAuthGuardContextMessage');
      let authGuardContext = new AuthGuardContext('You must sign in first', new AuthGuardAdditionalInfo());
      setTimeout(() => {
        mockAuthGuard.canActivate();
        expect(component.handleAuthGuardContextMessage).toHaveBeenCalledWith(authGuardContext);
      }, 1000);
    });
```

I suspect, the issue has to do with the fact that both test cases run their `expect` after 1000 milliseconds and one is probably overriding the othe, but I am not sure as I don't know how `jasmine` schedules the different `it`

Comment: There was an old [comedy routinee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_and_Dale): *SMITH: Doctor, it hurts when I do this. DALE: Don't do that.*  It sounds like these particular tests merit separate "describe", doesn't it?

Comment: That I understand but why ?

Comment: Have you tried to use `done` to explicitly tell Jasmine when the test is finished? `fit('testcase', (done) => { setTimeout(() => { done(); }, 1000) }`.